# Access Class in different Threads

Tags: java

I'm building something here and I found myself in a pickle. Just some introduction first. I'm developing a client-server game. One of the functions it has is a chat that players can use to talk to another.

Player1 send a message to the server and the server forwards it to the respective Player2. My problemas is: how can I access classes from another thread so I can get the Socket object to relay the message to Player2.

```
        while (listening)
        {
            try 
            {
                //this is how I start a thread for each connection
                //do I need to use identifiers or something?
                new Client(serverSocket.accept()).start();
            }
            catch(IOException A)
            {
               reportError(A.toString()); //reportError is a function of mine
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to achieve this, the easiest would be:

```
public void start(){
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Starting server on port: " + port);
            while (serverState) {
                Socket socket = ss.accept();
                //stop server 
                if (!serverState) {
                    break;
                }

                Client handler = new Client(this, socket);
                handler.start();
            }
            //when server is stopped, close all connections

            for (Client client : clients.values()) {
                client.closeConnection();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

if you send "this" inside the constructor of client and set it as a private variable you could Access it from the run function(other thread)